# Laravel 5 relationship not working

Tags: mysql, laravel, relationship

I have courses and subscription types.
A subscribed user has a subscription type, i want all the courses that a users subscription type matches.

My attempt (which returns all the courses, not just the right ones):

```
$courses = Course::has('maintask')->with(['subscriptionType' => function ($q) use ($user)
        {
            return $q->where('subscription_type_id',$user->subscription[0]->subscription_type_id)->where('status','1');
        }])->get();
```

Any tips?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`whereHas()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence):

```
$courses = Course::has('maintask')
    ->whereHas('subscriptionType', function ($q) use ($user) {
        $q->where('id', $user->subscription[0]->subscription_type_id)
          ->where('status', 1);
    })->get();
```